# Java Spring Boot - error on GET request on PostMan

Tags: spring-boot, request, get, postman

I'm implementing a petshop gestor using SpringBoot. When I send a GET request I get an error response
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN6QI.png), [error from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDKxg.png)

Get function, from my ClientController:

```
@GetMapping("/clients")
    public List<Client> listAll(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

I expected to receive the list from all entities register on certain table, but actually I receive an error.

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: Please share the repsonse header, so we can see the http return code

Comment: @Jens Added too

Comment: That are only the request header, not the response header. Can you try to call  `curl -v <your url>` and post the result as text

Comment: @Jens Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Comment: I guess you are using your entities in your REST API. Don't do it. Learn about proper 3tier architecture

Comment: Yes, I created Model classes for each entity

Comment: I managed to solve part of the problem: adding JsonManagedReference in Client class, JsonBackReference in Pet class. Despite this, i can get the clients data with their pet list, but cant get pets data with their owners(client_id column), just their other data.

Comment: can you share how are calling repository in your controller (how are you injecting your dependencies)

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen Problem got solved. Thanks for trying to help